# How should I go about indenting somewhat complex block of code in Python/Selenium?

Tags: python, list, selenium

I'm fairly new to python/selenium and I'm having an issue wrapping my head around how to indent this particular block of code.
code:

```
articles = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('article')
for article in articles:
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(article).perform()
if article.find_element_by_tag_name('a').text == "sold out":
     print("sold out")
else:
    print("available")
        shirts = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id='container']/article/div/h1/a""")
        colors = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id='container']/article/div/p/a""")
    for shirt, color in zip(shirts, colors):
        shirt_text = shirt.text
        color_text = color.text
    print shirt_text, color_text
            link = article.find_element_by_xpath('div/a').get_attribute('href')
            print(link)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
articles = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('article')
for article in articles:
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(article).perform()
    if article.find_element_by_tag_name('a').text == "sold out":
         print("sold out")
    else:
        print("available")
        shirts = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id='container']/article/div/h1/a""")
        colors = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id='container']/article/div/p/a""")
        for shirt, color in zip(shirts, colors):
            shirt_text = shirt.text
            color_text = color.text
            print shirt_text, color_text
            link = article.find_element_by_xpath('div/a').get_attribute('href')
            print(link)
```